# Jquery condense statements without losing readability

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about condensing this?  Is there a better way?

```
        // Add wrapper tags
        $(this).append('<div class="jC2_Outer">');
        $(this).append('<div class="jC2_Toolbar">');
        $(this).append('<a href="#">Copy</a>');
        $(this).append('<a href="#">Plain Text</a>');
        $(this).append('<a href="#">Link</a>');
        $(this).append('<a href="#">Help</a>');
        $(this).append('</div>');
        $(this).append('<div class="jC2_Container">rg');
```

Also, the append function closes the divs, how should I be adding these onto the document so they don't close?  Doing this at the moment which isn't working:

```
$('.inner').append('</div></div>');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join an Array.

```
var content = [
'<div class="jC2_Outer">',
    '<div class="jC2_Toolbar">',
        '<a href="#">Copy</a>',
        '<a href="#">Plain Text</a>',
        '<a href="#">Link</a>',
        '<a href="#">Help</a>',
        '<div class="jC2_Container">rg</div>',
    '</div>',
 '</div>'
];

$(this).append(content.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '';

str += '<div class="jC2_Outer">';
str += '<div class="jC2_Toolbar">';
str += '<a href="#">Copy</a>';
str += '<a href="#">Plain Text</a>';
str += '<a href="#">Link</a>';
str += '<a href="#">Help</a>';
str += '</div>';
str += '<div class="jC2_Container">rg';

$(this).append(str);
```

Each time your doing `$(this)`, you're building new jQuery object, which isn't optimal. At the least you should be caching it:

```
var self = $(this);

self.append(...);
self.append(...);
self.append(...);
```

Whenever you using `append()`, the HTML included must be valid (all closed). You cannot close the tags you opened in another `append()` later down the line. Otherwise they will be closed for you, so you end up with:

```
$(this).append('<div class="jC2_Outer"></div>');
$(this).append('<div class="jC2_Toolbar"></div>');
$(this).append('<a href="#">Copy</a>');
$(this).append('<a href="#">Plain Text</a>');
$(this).append('<a href="#">Link</a>');
$(this).append('<a href="#">Help</a>');
//....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var mytext='<div class="jC2_Outer">\
        <div class="jC2_Toolbar">\
        <a href="#">Copy</a>\
        <a href="#">Plain Text</a>\
        <a href="#">Link</a>\
        <a href="#">Help</a>\
        </div>\
        <div class="jC2_Container">rg';
$(this).append(mytext);
```

This offers better optimization in that your not creating a new jquery object each time and it's also a lot less to type.

Comment: Be wary using the "\" in strings to wrap the string on multiple lines. Even a loose space after a "\" will result in a parse error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).append(
    '<div class="jC2_Outer">'
  + '<div class="jC2_Toolbar">'
  + '<a href="#">Copy</a>'
  + '<a href="#">Plain Text</a>'
  + '<a href="#">Link</a>'
  + '<a href="#">Help</a>'
  + '</div>'
  + '<div class="jC2_Container">rg'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you append the whole HTML chunk in only one append() call ?

```
$(this).append('<div class="jC2_Outer"><div class="jC2_Toolbar"><a href="#">Copy</a><a href="#">Plain Text</a><a href="#">Link</a><a href="#">Help</a></div><div class="jC2_Container">rg</div></div>');
```

Comment: it appears that he doesn't know how to make multiline strings, see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple ways; it's hard to see what you're trying to do without the context. But here are a couple choices:

Chaining:

```
$(this).append('<div class="jC2_Outer">')
       .append('<div class="jC2_Toolbar">')
       .append('<a href="#">Copy</a>')
       .append('<a href="#">Plain Text</a>')
       .append('<a href="#">Link</a>')
       .append('<a href="#">Help</a>')
       .append('<div class="jC2_Container"></div>');
```

Concatenation:

```
$(this).append('<div class="jC2_Outer">\
                <div class="jC2_Toolbar">\
                <a href="#">Copy</a>\
                <a href="#">Plain Text</a>\
                <a href="#">Link</a>'\
                <a href="#">Help</a>\
                </div>\
                <div class="jC2_Container">');
```

Comment: @philwinkle, Your chaining example is bad practice and like Matt said, you cannot span multiple lines without a backslash.

Comment: The second one won't work, and you should remove the `.append('</div>')` from the first version since jQuery appends elements, not tags.

Comment: Well, in the middle of an edit the criticism starts rolling in - will be more mindful in the future.

Comment: @nick - please show me a documented example where chaining is *bad practice*

Comment: @philwinkle, I should clarify, chaining in a general sense is good practice, chaining because you don't know how to span multiple lines when building a string is bad practice. AKA a "band-aid."

Comment: Another consideration is that every `.append()` independently modifies the DOM, which tends to be an expensive operation. It's typically better to perform one consolidated DOM modification.

Comment: I'll +1 the chaining because you don't know a better way being a 'band-aid'!